# Is there a way we can get .form /schema file for an existing PDF form

Tags: botframework

Is there a way we can get .form /schema file for an existing PDF form , There is one schema given in this link https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/experimental/generation/docs/example-schemas/sandwich.schema

How to handle existing forms any suggestions

Comment: Is my answer acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

Dialog generation is still experimental, so there's not currently a way to create schemas automatically. However, there are plans to introduce features in the future that will make it easier to create schemas. You can read more in the docs: https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/experimental/generation/docs